# Is there a way to exclude the site collection footer from the search?

Tags: search, master-page, crawling

I have two site collections inside my SharePoint application; team site & community site. I have added the following customeFooter Div to the seatle.master to display our company name as a footer as follow:-

```
<div id="customFooter"  >&copy; Our Company 2013</div>
    </div>
    </SharePoint:SharePointForm>
    <SharePoint:AjaxDelta id="DeltaPlaceHolderUtilityContent" runat="server">
    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="PlaceHolderUtilityContent" runat="server"/>
    </SharePoint:AjaxDelta>
    <SharePoint:ScriptBlock runat="server">
    var g_Workspace = "s4-workspace";
    </SharePoint:ScriptBlock>
    </body>.
```

But I have noted that in case a user search for our company name “Our Company”, then all the pages will be displayed in the search because they have the company name as the footer . can anyone advice how I can solve this issue, and how to exclude the footer from being crawl ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add `class="noindex"` to your footer `<div>`

See [Control Search Indexing (Crawling) Within a Page with Noindex](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/markarend/archive/2010/06/07/control-search-indexing-crawling-within-a-page-with-noindex.aspx)

Comment: Is this really working? I know there where huge problems with using this class in 2010, and I have spotted the same behavior in 2013. Maybe we have been using it wrong. See for example this question: http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/53280/search-not-respecting-noindex

Comment: As long as it's a simple div as the one here it should work. As far as I know the problem is "only" that SharePoint search doesn't support nested divs

Comment: i added this but it did not exclude the footer from the search. maybe because the footer was already crawled before adding the noindex class ?!!

Comment: A full crawl will be needed. As SharePoint will not think the pages have been changed, when it's the Master page that has the change